# Task.Run().Wait() is not working in Onstart() but it is working in App constructor of Xamarin.Forms

Tags: c#, asynchronous, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I am facing with an interesting issue which I couldnt figure out what might be the cause.

I am trying to handle an asynchronous task to check if there is active subscription for my app. It is working if it is done in App Constructor. But it doesnt work when it is placed in Onstart()

Here; It is working as I expect. It calls BillingTasks.WasItemPurchasedAsync() and wait until it is completed.

```
    public App()
    {
        ....
        
        if (!Properties.ContainsKey("IsSubscribed"))
        {
            bool WasPurchased = false;

            Task.Run(async () =>
            {
                WasPurchased = await BillingTasks.WasItemPurchasedAsync();
            }).Wait();
            Application.Current.Properties["IsSubscribed"] = WasPurchased;
        }
        ....
    }
```

But when I put the same code in OnStart(), It seems the task never ends and it crash. So what might be the reason for such different behaviour?

```
    protected override void OnStart()
    {   
        ....
        
        if (!Properties.ContainsKey("IsSubscribed"))
        {
            bool WasPurchased = false;

            Task.Run(async () =>
            {
                WasPurchased = await BillingTasks.WasItemPurchasedAsync();
            }).Wait();
            Application.Current.Properties["IsSubscribed"] = WasPurchased;
        }
        ....
    }
```

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2013/march/async-await-best-practices-in-asynchronous-programming

Answer (score 0):

From [Async/Await - Best Practices in Asynchronous Programming](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2013/march/async-await-best-practices-in-asynchronous-programming) document, suggest prefer **async Task** methods over **async void** methods.

`OnStart()` is not an event handler, override this method to perform actions when the application starts.

As a work around you can create your own custom event and handler that will allow for an `async void` to be performed on your event handler. You will subscribe to the event when `OnStart` is invoked by the application and then raise the custom event to be handled asynchronously.

```
 private event EventHandler Starting = delegate { };

    protected override void OnStart()
    {
        //subscribe to event
        Starting += onStarting;
        //raise event
        Starting(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }

    private async void onStarting(object sender, EventArgs args)
    {
        //unsubscribe from event
        Starting -= onStarting;
        //perform non-blocking actions
        await checksubscriptionAsync();
    }

    private async Task checksubscriptionAsync()
    {
        await ...
    }
```

Comment: Interesting. Two questions. (1) How do you guarantee that the work performed by the onStarting handler is complete before its side effects are needed? (2) How are exceptions in the handler observed?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It is a a good  to get around the issue. But I need checksubscriptionAsync() to complete all checks before mainPage is loaded. Using Event handler enable the application to continue to load the mainpage.. and most of the times, pages loaded before asynchronous checks are complete.so It seems the most efficient way is to utilize Task.Run().Wait() in the constructor.

Comment: @TiTus So you add Task.Run().Wait() in the constructor finally.

Comment: @Cherry Bu. Yes.

Answer (score 0):

> It seems the task never ends and it crash.

I'm not sure why that would happen, but it could be Xamarin itself protecting you. Blocking the UI thread is bad for Desktop apps, but is considered *especially* rude on mobile devices, since the *entire screen* becomes unresponsive. For this reason, some app stores will automatically check for this behavior in an emulator and reject your app if it behaves this way.

The proper solution is to take some UX guidance from [Async MVVM Data Binding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2014/march/async-programming-patterns-for-asynchronous-mvvm-applications-data-binding). Specifically, you do *not* want to block the UI thread until your subscription check is done. Instead, show some kind of "Loading..." screen while asynchronously running the subscription check. Then, based on the result, switch to either the main app screen or a signup screen or an error screen.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I think, using Task.Run().Wait() in the constructor also blocks the UI, doesnt it? Actually, it is not an issue for me to block the UI for a while. I will check the guidence you suggested.